# javascript arraylist

Tags: javascript

Can we attach arraylist or function with a javascript object at runtime

```
function abc(){
        this.a = 1;
        this.b = 2;
    }
    var obj = new abc();
    obj.list.add("abc"); // list is not declare in class  abc
```

Comment: @Arslan Ahson I think you should read a little and then come here to ask questions that are explained even in Wikipedia!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function abc(){
    this.a = 1;
    this.b = 2;
}
var obj = new abc();
obj.list = ["abc"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = new abc();
obj.list = [];
obj.list.unshift("abc");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function abc(){
        this.a = 1;
        this.b = 2;
    }
    var obj = new abc();
    obj.list = new Array();
    obj.list.push("abc");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write

```
obj.push("abc")
```

Answer (score 0):

you will first have to declare the list, then you could access/modify it as any other object prop :

```
 var obj = new abc();
 obj.list = [];//or obj.list = new Array();
 obj.list.add("abc");
```